# How to add ringing artifacts?

Tags: effects

A ringing artifact is one where edges will have a sort of high-contrasting banding pattern across them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts

[image]

Even better would be to have multiple ringing bands, as seen here using a sinc filter:

[image]

I already have one way of adding this type of artifact by [resampling it with a windowed sinc filter in ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/#windowed), but I would like to be able to add this in blender directly. How do I do this?

Comment: save to a jpeg file with a low quality. You'll see lots of those.

Comment: @cegaton I already have a better way to do it that I linked to. But yes, if there were no other way I definitely might try that.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a *Sharpen* filter in the compositor:

[image]

Comment: You could add a blur node after sharpen to optain something closer to the example